# How to get full path name of a Linux command

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find out the file path of commands in Linux e.g., `ls` has file path as `/bin/ls`. How can I find out the exact path of some commands?

Comment: use [which](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) eg: `which ls`

Comment: `which` is the way to go. but because i is not mentioned yet: `locate` is also pretty useful sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out, `which <progName>` would do it. You could also try:

```
whereis -b <progName>
```

This will list all the paths that contains `progName`. I.e `whereis -b gcc` on my machine returns:

```
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/bin/X11/gcc
```

Comment: On my machine I have `/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/gcc` (both of which are links which after many links point to the actual program which is `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9`), but the former isn't listed in `whereis gcc`.

Comment: `whereis -b` does not work for the `type` is it a normal case?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `which`, it give you path of command:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

you can use `type`:

```
 $ type ls
 ls is /bin/ls
```

Comment: Well done with the use of `type` which is generally a builtin, and if not provided by POSIX. `type -p` (where that option is available) will return a pruned result which can be assigned and used as a command. e.g. `myprog=$(type -p someexename)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yea right, thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command. In case of a command in your `$PATH` it will show you the full path:

```
mureinik@computer ~ $ which cp
/usr/bin/cp
```

And it will also show details about aliases:

```
mureinik@computer ~ $ which ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    /usr/bin/ls
```

Comment: No details for aliases on my Ubuntu v16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can find it with `which` command

```
which <command>
```

eg `which cat`

```
/bin/cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify, which shell you are going to use, but I strongly recommend using `which`, as it does not necessarily do, what you expect. Here two examples, where the result possibly is not what you expect:

(1) Example with *bash*, and the command `echo`:

```
 which echo
```

would output `/usr/bin/echo`, but if you use the `echo` command in your bash script, /usr/bin/echo is **not** executed. Instead, the builtin command `echo` is executed, which is similar, but not identical in behaviour.

(2) Example with *zsh*, and the command `which`:

```
which which
```

would output the message `which: shell built-in command` (which is correct, but certainly not a file path, as you requested), while

```
/usr/bin/which which
```

would output the file path `/usr/bin/which`, but (as in the bash example) this is not what's getting executed when you just type `which`.

There are cases, when you **know** for sure (because you know your application), that `which` will produce the right result, but beware that as soon as builtin-commands, aliases and shell functions are involved, you need first to decide how you want to handle those cases, and then choose the appropriate tools depending on the kind of shell which you are using.